# How do you get access to a testing device's files when running instrumentation tests for Android

Tags: android, mediastore, instrumented-test

I have set up a physical device with files that can be retrieved through the MediaStore. My goal is to retrieve these files through the MediaStore in an instrumented test.

Currently, when I push the debug app to the device and test it manually, the device files are found. The problem is when I am running instrumentation tests, and I get nothing from the MediaStore.

Is there a way to get the files through the MediaStore in an instrumentation test?

Possible relevant: I define and use a dummy Activity in my instrumentation test class

```
        Looper.prepare()
        dummyActivity = DummyActivity()
```

I then tried to define the dummy Activity in the debug folder, declare it in the debug manifest, and instantiate it via an ActivityScenario. Didn't help.

Comment: This is rather theoretical and not reproducible; besides you might defeat the idea of instrumentation testing with that `DummyActivity`.

Comment: As I understand it, the idea of instrumentation testing is to have an application context.

Comment: @MartinZeitler Is it not practical to set up devices with files, and then run a test to determine if the MediaStore query your app uses is correct? It really should be.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I think you are mistaken. It was straightforward to achieve the desired outcome. As far as being reproducible, do you care to expand? What about preloading a test device with files, and then running a test that depends on those files is not reproducible?

Answer (score 0):

I made the assumption that manifest permissions carried over to test package from the debug package. Not so.

Adding the following line to my test class made the MediaStore query return the files on the device!

```
    @get:Rule
    var mRuntimePermissionRule = GrantPermissionRule.grant(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
```